# Image moving down inside of div

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create some divs to hold a bunch of images. Just to test I only put in 1 image for now. My problem is that it moves down 3 pixels.
As far as I can tell it is because I have a 3 pixel margin on the container div, but I dont understand why is has any influence on the image.
I have tried to set the following for the image but nothing seems to work.

```
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:0;
line-height:0;
```

http://testdummies.dk/8pane/glue.php

```
<div class="box small">
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Noah_Webster_200x200.jpg">
</div>

.box {
    background-color: #B9C4F4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

I have been pulling hairs for several hours trying to figure this out but haven't gotten anywhere.

Any help is greatly appriciated!

Resin

Comment: when you fill each box with images they will align perfectly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happening because of positioning inline element (img) inside inline-block;

1. Apply `display:block;` for image.
   **OR**
2. Set your `.box {display: block; float: left; }`

Comment: You don't have to declare `display: block;` if you `float` your element

Comment: Of course not. I did it to the contrary of display: inline-block, which was set before.